# Bypassing Squid/SquidGuard blacklist in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, squid, blacklist

I've recently gone about setting up and configuring a linux box with ubuntu 14 for the purposes of providing a proxy server to a school curriculum network.

Everything has gone well and is up and running, however I've noticed something which concerns me.

I won't list the website url as not to offend anybody (this is just an example) so I will refer to it as

www.blockedsite.com/blockedpage

This url (and 10000's of others) are present in my black list, and when trying to visit the site you get the expected forbidden/access denied error as you would hope.

However!

if I just type the URL as blockedsite.com/blockedpage (without the leading http:// or www.)
then It loads the page without question - Very Bad!

Of course, this doesn't seem to happen in IE as it always adds the https prefix to the start of the URL. This problem is happening in Chrome.. and unfortunately it's something we use.

Can anyone advise as to how to tackle this problem?

Kind Regards
James

Answer (score 0):

Those blacklists do an exact match of your string with what the URL is. You probably have "http://" or "www" in your blacklist and google does not add those.

Proof:

I downloaded one of the example files from [here](http://www.squidguard.org/blacklists.html)

```
./blacklists/ads$ more urls
thisisarandomentrythatdoesnotexist.com/foo
```

and there are several more.

ALL of them do NOT have "http" or "www." in front of the URL so the answer is indeed: remove anything from the `www.` and in front of it from your blacklist. Simple reason: this works for http, https, ftp and many more protocols and even for protocols yet to be invented.